# Trying to favorite a tweet/status

Tags: php, api, twitter

Made a connection using $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(....
Have been successfully making tweets this way..

So, I'm trying to favorite a tweet/status, like this:

```
$the_tweet = 239128150125191168;

$connection->request('POST', $connection->url('1/favorites/create'), array('id' => $the_tweet));
```

and it's giving me a 400 error code. Can't figure out why. If I use GET, I get a 200, but it doesn't favorite the tweet. It's gotta be a POST, that's what the definition says to use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work if you do:

```
$connection->request('POST', $connection->url('1/favorites/create/'.$the_tweet.'.json') );
```

If you notice here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/favorites/create/%3Aid
"POSTDATA" is none.

Comment: This returns a 404 error code. If I do this: $connection->request('POST', $connection->url('1/statuses/update'), array('status' => $the_tweet));  it posts a status fine.

Comment: btw I can try to do the favorites/create from the web browser and it just complains that I don't have authentication. The status/tweet id definitely exists

Comment: Can you post the full response in both cases (400 and 404)?